# helm_release.teleport: timeout while waiting for state to become 'Running'

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubectl, terraform0.11, terraform-enterprise

I have been getting the following error below:

```
Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error occurred:
    * module.cluster.module.teleport.helm_release.teleport: 1 error occurred:
    * module.cluster.module.teleport.helm_release.teleport: helm_release.teleport: timeout while waiting for state to become 'Running' (last state: 'Pending', timeout: 5m0s)
```

I looked to see what pods it could be referring to but there are no pods in the cluster.

```
 $ kubectl get pods
No resources found in default namespace.
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Try listing pods from all namespaces when faced with `No resources found in default namespace` error.

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```